# igraph assortativity by group

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

The `igraph` function `assortativity_nominal()` in `R` returns a coefficient for the whole graph.
This is not very informative as this treats each node homogeneously.

Instead it might be that nodes from one group are very assortative while nodes from other groups aren't.
Is there a way to calculate the assortativity coefficient for each group in a network?

Example below:

```
# group = group of individual in `to`
data <- data.frame(
      group = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"),
      from = c(NA, NA, "WtYSxS", "WtYSxS", "HmPsw2", "HmPsw2", "2Kxtgd", "8PPM98", "2Kxtgd", "2Kxtgd", "Rn7YC7", "8PPM98", "TDNbL6", "TDNbL6", "m6Qzts", "JBm5SV", "JBm5SV", "PeJJDM"),
      to = c("HmPsw2", "WtYSxS", "2Kxtgd", "H9xtgn", "1TlDJE", "8PPM98", "Rn7YC7", "NHoRoo", "nRkdi0", "TDNbL6", "m6Qzts", "JBm5SV", "xTtubP", "wi8Yxa", "PeJJDM", "gctfjW", "eomyRJ", "E4FjqU")
    )
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
data_edges = data %>% drop_na(from) %>% select(from, to)
data_vertices = data %>% select(to, group)

g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d = data_edges,
                                   vertices = data_vertices,
                                   directed = TRUE)

igraph::assortativity_nominal(
  g,
  as.integer(as.factor(V(g)$group))
)
[1] 0.6363636
```

The coefficient above tells me that there is relatively high assorative mixing but it doesn't describle to me the details of that mixing. It could be that people from group A mix assortatively with other people from group A; while people from group B mix homogeneously with everyone.

Comment: I'm looking into the same question and I think I might have come across an answer. Not sure if it's right (am researching it further to see) but I figure I'd write something down here anyway. It seems like Coleman's homophily index might be what we're looking for, in the netseg package. See the bottom at this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/netseg/readme/README.html